# How to takes drop-down items value from database connected in Progress 4gl, Open Edge?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have created one simple window with one drop down box and the project already connected with default sports database. now i want to show all the tables in database in that drop down box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to dynamically fill the contents of a combo-box, you need to dynamically create it:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE ComboBoxWidgetHandle AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
CREATE COMBO-BOX ComboBoxWidgetHandle.
```

After that, you can use the widget handle to add elements to the combo-box, by using the database metaschema table called '_file':

```
FOR EACH _file NO-LOCK WHERE _Hidden = NO:
    ComboBoxWidgetHandle:ADD-FIRST (_file._FILE-NAME).
END.
```

If you also want to know the other properties of the _file metaschema table, just try a

```
FOR EACH _file NO-LOCK WHERE _Hidden = NO:
    DISPLAY _file.
END.
```

and you'll get an overview over that metaschema table.

Comment: Can't you grab a static combo-box's handle and manipulate it that way?

Comment: good point, you could, but you'd have to initialize a static combobox without any entries first, which seemed more confusing to me...

Comment: Two things about getting the list of tables:  1) You should use NO-LOCK; and 2) You usually only want the tables that are part of the application -- not the system tables.  So, generally, you would use something like: FOR EACH _File NO-LOCK WHERE _Hidden = NO: